# Scala parsers to build a simple calculator example

Tags: scala, parsing

We have the following code.Available at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JIJ230HAQZ2pqD5qdXSRRw

It works when the input is for example `1+1` but for some reason it cannot match `1-1` and it gives syntax error.

Can you please help?

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class  OurParsers extends RegexParsers {

  def expression: Parser[Expression] = addSub
  
  def addSub = (add | sub)

  def add: Parser[Expression] = productDivision ~ rep("+" ~> productDivision) ^^ {
    case p ~ Nil => p
    case p ~ prods => Sum(p, prods)
  }

  def sub: Parser[Expression] = productDivision ~ rep("-" ~> productDivision) ^^ {
    case p ~ Nil => p
    case p ~ prods => Subtract(p, prods)
  }

  def productDivision: Parser[Expression] = term ~ rep("*" ~> term) ^^ {
    case t ~ Nil => t
    case t ~ terms => Product(t, terms)
  }

  def term: Parser[Expression] = number | "(" ~> expression <~ ")"

  def number: Parser[Number] = """(\+|\-)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?""".r ^^ {
    case num => Number(num.toDouble)
  }
}

trait Expression {
  def execute: Double
}

case class Sum(val operand1: Expression, val operands: List[Expression]) extends Expression {
  def execute =
    operand1.execute + operands.map(_.execute).reduce(_+_)
}

case class Subtract(val operand1: Expression, val operands: List[Expression]) extends Expression {
  def execute =
    operand1.execute - operands.map(_.execute).reduce(_-_)
}

case class Product(val operand1: Expression, val operands: List[Expression]) extends Expression {
  def execute =
    operand1.execute * operands.map(_.execute).reduce(_*_)
}

case class Division(val operand1: Expression, val operands: List[Expression]) extends Expression {
  def execute =
    operand1.execute / operands.map(_.execute).reduce(_/_)
}

case class Number(val value: Double) extends Expression {
  def execute = value
}

val parsers = new OurParsers

val result = parsers.parseAll(parsers.expression, "1-1")
    result match {
      case result: parsers.Failure => throw new Exception("syntax error")
      case _ => {
        val exp = result.get  // get the expression from the tree
        println("tree: " + exp.toString)
        val value = exp.execute  // execute the expression
        println(value.toString)  // return string representation of result
      }
    }
```

Comment: Using `def addSub = (add ||| sub)` solves the issue. But I do not have much experience using scala parsers, so I think you might just take a moment to see if it's suitable for you.

Comment: The only drawback with that operator is that we cannot perform operations like `1+1-1` only `(1+1)-1`. Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `-` can be either a part of a number or a binary operation.  You are binding `-` to be a part of a `number` before you get to `sub`. So you have a `term` `term` sequence, when you wanted to have `term` `-` `term`.

You'd have to change your grammar to avoid this issue, or keep on writing things like `1-(1)` as `-(1)` would not be parsed as number (although it suggest that you won't parse `-` as unary operation, so grammar change could be better).